# How to take the first N Promises that pass a filter?

Tags: javascript, promise

If I have an array of values, and I use those values to perform a check that performs a promise, how do I take the first N Promises that pass a check?

For the following example, I just want the first three odd numbers, as determined by the function, `isOdd`, that returns a promise.

```
const collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const len = collection.length;
const results = [];
let index = -1;

function isOdd(value) {
    if (value % 2 !== 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(1);
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(0);
    }
}

while (++index < len) {
    const currentValue = collection[index];

    const result = isOdd(currentValue);

    // append the result to an array of results IF Promise.resolve's value === 1

    if (results.length >== 3) {
        break;
    }
}

Promise.all(results).then(doMoreStuff);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm restating the problem a bit to assume that the "filter" you mention is actually a promise being fulfilled vs. rejected, not fulfilling with 0 vs. 1. In other words:

```
function isOdd(value) {
  if (value % 2 !== 0) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    return Promise.reject();
  }
}
```

You just need to write the logic.

```
function takeFirstN(promises, n) {
  const results = [];

  if (!promises.length) return Promise.resolve([]);

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    for (promise of promises) {
      promise.then(result => {
        results.push(result);
        if (!(--n)) resolve(results);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

In other words, kick off all the promises. As each one resolves, put its result on a list of results, and check to see if *n* promises have resolved, in which case resolve the overall promise.

Then:

```
const collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
takefirstN(collection.map(isOdd), 3)
  .then(results => console.log(results));
```

This does not deal with the case where less than *n* promises fulfill, or handle edge cases such as *n* being greater than the number of promises. That is left as an exercise.

#### Original problem

If you want to stick with your definition of promises which fulfill with a value of either 0 or 1, then arrange to pass a predicate (called `filter` here) to a `takeFirstNWhich` function as follows:

```
function takeFirstNWhich(promises, filter, n) {
  const results = [];

  if (!promises.length) return Promise.resolve([]);

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    for (promise of promises) {
      promise.then(result => {
        if (filter(result)) {
          results.push(result);
          if (!(--n)) resolve(results);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Now you can write:

```
takefirstNWhich(collection.map(isOdd), odd => odd, 3)
  .then(results => console.log(results));
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I learned a great deal about when/how to utilize the executor in the Promise constructor. I'm going to accept.

I do have a follow-up question though:

In your implementation, you had `collection.map`, what it if I want to save time and not run the mapping function  on the entire collection, but rather iterate, and stop once I have 3 promises that resolved to 1?

Comment: You can't know which promises are going to resolve until you create and run them.

Comment: Thanks again @torazaburo, you've been super helpful.

Comment: +1, but "left as exercise" needs more emphasis. Without handling rejections correctly, the code should not be used in production. Btw, if you're using Bluebird you don't have to implement this stuff yourself but can use [`some`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html)

Answer (score -1):

Promises aren't blocking so there's no real way to stop running them when others have finished. The closest I can think of would look like this.

```
const collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const len = collection.length;
const results = [];
let index = -1;

function isOdd(value) {
    if (value % 2 !== 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(1);
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(0);
    }
}

while (++index < len) {
    const currentValue = collection[index];

    if(results.length < 3) {
      isOdd(currentValue).then(
        function(result) {
          if(result == 1) {
            results.push(currentValue);
          }
        }
      );
    }
}

Promise.all(results).then(
  function() { 
    alert("done: " + results.join(', ');
  ); 
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39jm96sa/1/)

But as you see that grabs all of the odd values. you could move the `if(results.length < 3)...` to the resolve function but that won't stop it from running on every element just how many it returns.

Comment: But this won't work. The `Promise.all` will be called before anything has been pushed onto `results`.